# Dependency Injection vs. Dependency Lookup

Tags: dependency-injection

Не могу понять разницу между этими понятиями. Прочитал несколько статей в интернете, в результате - в голове каша, каждый автор объясняет суть по-разному. В чём ключевое отличие этих разновидностей IoC? И где они могут быть применены, кроме юнит-тестов?

Comment: Dependency Injection: зависимости передаются в объект извне. т.е. тот кто создает объект, тот ему зависимости и предоставляет. Dependency Lookup: зависимости объекту не передаются извне. объект сам решает как и когда ему запросить зависимости

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно почитать [Фаулера](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#ServiceLocatorVsDependencyInjection) по этому поводу:

> Основное различие между двумя потернами в том, как реализация
>   предоставляется классу приложения. С service locator'ом  класс явно
>   запрашивает реализацию у локатора. При использовании DI нет явного
>   запроса, сервис появится в классе приложения - отсюда и термин
>   "инверсия контроля".